# For Loop or Dim for getting a handle on data from a Datagrid in a Checkbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am currently trying to ' Loop ' through my DataGrid to check if the boxes that are ticked to be shown on another page that pretty much looks like my existing one.
I'm having trouble finding out how to actually do a ' loop ' as they are called I think as I am a slow learner in coding , am just looking for some guidance in how I would achieve this goal of actually getting a handle on the Data. Below is my code for the ASP.GridView & well there is no VB.NET code-behind as of such because well , am stuck & need pushing the right direction . 
EDIT: Forgot to mention , why cant I do this from  a Dim This As String?

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="100%">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table width="100%" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt" cellpadding="0"
                    cellspacing="0" border="1">
                    <tr align="left">
                        <th colspan="4">
                            Customer:
                            <asp:Label ID="Customer_lab" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </th>
                        <th colspan="4">
                            Quote:
                            <asp:Label ID="Quote_lab" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </th>
                        <th colspan="4">
                            Project:
                            <asp:Label ID="Project_lab" runat="server"></asp:Label></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th></th>
                        <th>
                            CODE
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            DESCRIPTION
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            LENGTH
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            WIDTH
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            QTY
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            COST
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            £M2
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            £UNIT
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            SUPPLIER</th>
                        <th>
                            QTY</th>
                        <th>
                            DUE DATE</th>
                    </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkItem" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td style="width: 150px">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Code") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Length") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Width") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Qty")  %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Cost") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("M2") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SHT") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DD1" Width="100%" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt">
                        </asp:DropDownList></td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Qty_Txt1" OnTextChanged="GetData" OnDataBinding='<%# Eval("Code") %>'
                            AutoPostBack="true" Width="80%" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Date1" Width="90%" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <b>
                            <asp:Label ID="New_Lab" Font-Size="8pt" runat="Server"></asp:Label></b></td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DD2" Width="100%" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList></td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Qty_Txt2" AutoPostBack="true" Width="80%" Font-Names="Verdana"
                            Font-Size="8pt" runat="Server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Date2" Width="90%" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" runat="Server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DD3" Width="100%" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList></td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Qty_Txt3" AutoPostBack="true" Width="80%" Font-Names="Verdana"
                            Font-Size="8pt" runat="Server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td width="8%">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Date3" Width="90%" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" runat="Server" ValidationGroup="PersonalInfoGroup">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:CustomValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"
                            controltovalidate="Date3"
                            OnServerValidate="Date3_Validator"
                            errormessage="Date Error!"
                            runat="Server">
                        </asp:CustomValidator></td>
                </tr>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="Supplier" Value='<%# Eval("cdf_supplier_tx") %>' runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="PrefSupplier" Value='<%# Eval("cdf_supplier_pref") %>' runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="Nominal" Value='<%# Eval("Nominal") %>' runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="QuoteCost" Value='<%# Eval("QuoteCost") %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <SeparatorStyle BackColor="#C0FFFF" />
            <SeparatorTemplate>
            </SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

EDIT: Some of the VB that's been tried and tested & A little of my own that G_Wilson has tried helping me with but i can't grasp on.

```
 Protected Sub Save_Btn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Save_Btn.Click
    'connection.Open()

    'command = New SqlCommand("Select * from impsod_h where [Quote Number]='" + HiddenQno.Value + "'", connection)
    'datareader = command.ExecuteReader()
    'If datareader.HasRows = False Then
    '    datareader.Close()
    '    CreateImpsod1()
    '    CreateIMPSOH1()
    '    installcalc()
    'Else
    '    datareader.Close()
    'End If
    'connection.Close()
    For Each Row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    Dim ThisCheck As String
        ThisCheck = ChkItem.Checked
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i think you will need is a `For Each` Loop.

That will look a little something like this :

```
For Each Row as GridViewRow in GridView1.Rows
    Dim chkSelect as CheckBox
    chkSelect = e.Row.FindControl("ChkItem")
    If chkSelect.Checked = True Then
        'Put vb.net logic here ...
    Else
        'Put anything else here ...
    End If
Next
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: This answer seems legit , will try it out & mark as answer if it actually works. Cheers!

Comment: This unfortunately isn't as clear as it makes out to be meaning I can't achieve my goal and mark as answer, Effort though.

Comment: If you could post you vb in the question, then i could improve my answer.

Comment: First you had my curiosity and now you have my attention , well done sir.

Comment: Your Welcome, Hope that has helped.